# Saga Redux not sending parameters in post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm using redux Saga for the first time for handling my API requests. 
I've got an async function that sends a simple post request like so:

```
const onLoginRequest = async (userName, password) =>
await fetch(`${loginApi}`, { method: 'POST', body: { userName:userName,password:password } })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => res)
  .catch(error => error);
```

if I send the userName and password in the querystring, it works fine. But when adding them to the Body of my POST, it shouts that they are undefined.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are serialize the JSON body like below

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  userName: userName,
  password: password
})
```